# vim 9.0, windows 10, newbie - shell commands don't work

Tags: shell, vim, windows-10

As preface, I am new to Vim and not expert on Windows OS.
Maybe I am doing something incorrectly.
I may not know how to express the issue correctly either:
Vim works great, but I am learning.
I run Vim from desktop short-cut, but get same result from command line.
I cannot get shell commands working in Vim.

For example: :!dir
Returns: "shell returns 1" and nothing more

Otherwise seems good: editting is fine, ctrl-d works, :cd works.

Please help: What is likely cause for shell command doesn't work.
I would like to use shell for printing, for example.

Comment: Please tell us where you've looked to research this. This is covered many times on the internet.

Comment: `:!dir`, .... Are you expecting the Windows `dir` command to work? OR do you have a "shell" (read *nix) alias `dir` that run `ls -l` (or similar) that you use from your command line? If the later, I'm pretty sure aliases aren't export to child processes, such as `vim` would be from a WSL bash environment. This may be more appropriate to [vi.se]. Delete here if you post there. Check their help for on-topic questions. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I thought that the DOS command dir would work as does the bash ls command in Linux. Perhaps, I am wrong in that which is why I was asking - perhaps it must be done differently? I google the subject and don't find relevant information using terms: "vim", "shell command", "windows", so perhaps I am not expressing it properly. Is it not a simple topic (for user) as it seems to be in Linux - simply ":!ls".

Comment: OK, On my system, Windows10->WSL->bash->vi, if I type `:! type dir` I get back `dir is a tracked alias for /usr/bin/dir` , No quickly obtainable info in tracked aliases, but if ancient memories are correct, type `rehash` from your command line before invoking `vim` may help. That's all I've got for now. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks you both, you led me to the answer - I was not aware there was a Vim forum on stack exchange and I needed to study the help text more carefully. Searching help with :help 'shell' gave me what I needed. There are about six related settings, three were not quite right but it was the value of "shell' that was the cause of the problem. The windows %SHELL% = C:/cygwin/mksnt/bash.exe is not correct - cygwin is not installed and Vim was copying this value. I simply had to set Vim 'shell' to C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe